# copying a message to another channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want the bot copy the number that user sends after typing a message and this is my code

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  // Command handler, seen previously
  if (message.content === '#مسعف') {
    message.channel
      .awaitMessages((m) => m.author.id == message.author.id, { max: 1 })
      .then((collected) => {
        // only accept messages by the user who sent the command
        // accept only 1 message, and return the promise after 30000ms = 30s

        // first (and, in this case, only) message of the collection
        if (message.content = 1 - 10000) {
          message.channel.send(message.content);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

I need bot sends the number that the user types it

Comment: What do you think this one checks? `if (message.content = 1-10000)`

Comment: the number that user types from 1-10000? @ZsoltMeszaros

Answer (score 3):

There are problems with `if (message.content = 1 - 10000)`. First, a single equal sign (`=`) is used for assignment. What you achieve with that code is that you change `message.content`'s value to -9,999. If you want to check the value of something, you'll need to use double (`==`) or triple equal signs (`===`). Also, if you want to check if a number is between two numbers, you need to check if the number is larger than the smaller number and if it's smaller than the larger one.

Another problem is that you're checking the content of the original `message` not the one you collected inside your message collector.

Check out the snippet below:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content === '#مسعف') {
    message.channel
      .awaitMessages((m) => m.author.id === message.author.id, { max: 1 })
      .then((collected) => {
        // first (and, in this case, only) message of the collection
        const response = collected.first();

        // check if it's a number
        if (isNaN(response.content))
          return message.channel.send(`${response.content} is not a number`);

        const num = parseInt(response.content);
        // check if num is between 1 and 10,000 (inclusive)
        if (num >= 1 && num <= 10000) {
          message.channel.send(num);
        } else {
          message.channel.send(`Nah, ${num} is not a valid number`);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

[image]